# AES word multiplication

Tags: aes

I'm studying AES encryption algorithm, but I can't understand word multiplication as requested by AES.
If I have this two words multiplication:

```
{a3}{a2}{a1}{a0} * {b3}{b2}{b1}{b0}
```

I arrived to write the polynomial:

```
{2d}x^6+{10}x^5+{1c}x^4+{29}x^2+{10}x+{18}
```

Now AES standard asks to divide the previous polynomial with

```
 x^4+1
```

and take coefficient the MOD of this division.
How can I make the division? I mean that I understand when  polynomial coefficients are 0 and 1 (bits), but when they are byte I really can't figure it out...

After reading other AES documents I suspect that word multiplication in AES is like the following matrix multiplication:

```
{a0}{a3}{a2}{a1}   {b0}
{a1}{a0}{a3}{a2} * {b1}
{a2}{a1}{a0}{a3}   {b2}
{a3}{a2}{a1}{a0}   {b3}
```

So in the end my result is:

```
{a3}{a2}{a1}{a0} * {b3}{b2}{b1}{b0} = {00}{04}{00}{04}.
```

**Is it correct for AES calculation?**

Comment: While this isn't entirely off-topic on Stack Overflow, I suspect this question would be a vastly better fit on (and see answers much more quickly on) http://crypto.stackexchange.com. If you're interested in migrating there, either (1) delete this question and then re-post it there or (2) `[flag]` this question for moderation attention and request migration. I don't know enough about AES internals to say for sure if this question is a perfect fit for Crypto.SE, but it seems pretty likely.

Comment: @apsillers It would be a good question on crypto, no doubt about that, and I would consider it very likely that it would fare better there. MaxV, always try include tags with a lot of followers (e.g. [tag:cryptography] would be a good one). If you cannot specify a runtime or programming environment, you may want to consider other (stackexchange) sites.